# How to change the default storage volume for EC2 which is launced by autoscaling group?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, autoscaling

My cdk script is like this, I want to expand default strage to 30 -> 60

```
const aiAutoScalingGroup = new autoscaling.AutoScalingGroup(this, 'ai-asg', {
  vpc,
  blockDevices:[
    {
      deviceName: "/dev/xvda",
      volume: ec2.BlockDeviceVolume.ebs(60, {
        volumeType: ec2.EbsDeviceVolumeType.GP3,
      }),
    }
  ],
  instanceType: new ec2.InstanceType('g4dn.xlarge'),
```

However it shows the error like this

```
'import("/Users/whitebear/MyCode/httproot/of/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2/lib/volume").BlockDeviceVolume' to type 'import("/Users/whitebear/MyCode/httproot/ of/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-autoscaling/lib/volume").BlockDeviceVolume' cannot be assigned.
  Type incompatible for property 'ebsDevice'.
    Type 'import("/Users/whitebear/MyCode/httproot/of/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-ec2/lib/volume").EbsDeviceProps | undefined' to type 'import("/Users/whitebear/MyCode Cannot assign to /httproot/of/node_modules/aws-cdk-lib/aws-autoscaling/lib/volume").EbsDeviceProps | undefined'
```

I guess it says BlockDeviceVolume of autoscaling is different from  BlockDeviceVolume of EC2.

If so , how can I change the default storage size of autoscaling group?